# What if I have one Nodejs installed on windows and I want to install nodejs on WSL? Do I need to uninstall node which is already installed on windows?

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

What if I have one Nodejs installed on windows and I want to install nodejs on WSL? Do I need to uninstall node which is already installed on windows?
I want to switch between node versions so I want to install nvm and node on WSL/WSL2.

What if I have one Nodejs installed on windows and I want to install nodejs on WSL? Do I need to uninstall node which is already installed on windows?

I'm stuck whether to keep or uninstall nodejs which is installed on windows. In some of the articles I saw that it conflicts with WSL nodejs

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to uninstall the one on Windows.**

It depends on which node executable you are using while compiling your project,

- if you put your project in the Windows file system then you can use your NodeJs on Windows
- if your project is in WSL, then you can use the NodeJs in WSL

There are no conflicts between these 2 env.